# Variable storing in Class File

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a list view in the Panorama item, i would like to redirect to a new page to display more details about the item i have selected. May i know how do i do about this?

My current idea is to , When clicked , it will store the variable into the class file and my the other form when loaded  it will always extract from that class file variable and search from the list.

I'm planning to keep a list of array, do i keep it in the class file so that it is accessible to all? If so , how do i do that too?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you could use up a lot of memory for transient data.  Have you considered just calling Navigate() to load your new page and passing the instantiating data as post data - [like here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626521%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).  This way you only create the new page with the data needed and don't hog memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a RingBuffer for this... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

And I would have the indexer return the Image associated with the index. I would additionally have the TotalFrames present and returned via the Length of the List entries or similar. (Even if past the bounds of the list by using modulo)

I would also have a float indexer which would operate on values such as `25.7` or a string operator which took Degrees form.

I would also overload the operators to allow for rotation based on these methods accordingly. (For sliding and gestures inter alia)

You would then have a single enumerator with two operating styles, a repeating and a non repeating for going through the frames (including in reverse)

And this was just off the top... don't make me do an example :p